# How to increment a variable on a for loop in jinja template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I would like to do something like:

variable p is from test.py which is a list ['a','b','c','d']

```
{% for i in p %}
{{variable++}}
{{variable}}
```

result output is:
1 2 3 4

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You could use `loop.index`:

```
{% for i in p %}
  {{ loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

Check the [template designer documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/).

In more recent versions, due to scoping rules, the following would *not* work:

```
{% set count = 1 %}
{% for i in p %}
  {{ count }}
  {% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49699589/5668215) answer to solve the scoping issue

Comment: @faruk13 Your tip solved my purpose :) and this answer also worked

Comment: @zeekay Please highlight this `due to scoping rules, the following would not work:` or make it `bold` almost pissed off

Comment: Note that `loop.index` starts from 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 126):

After 2.10, to solve the scope problem, you can do something like this:

```
{% set count = namespace(value=0) %}
{% for i in p %}
  {{ count.value }}
  {% set count.value = count.value + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I get the error:

TemplateSyntaxError at /listing/

Invalid block tag on line 145: 'set', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

On:
 {% set count = namespace(value=0) %}

Any idea of the cause of this?

Comment: In case you are working with django like me, do note that django does not support `set`.

I ended up solving it by defining a function within django model to do the calculation, as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48158461/4824639.

Answer (score 66):

As Jeroen says there are scoping issues: if you set 'count' outside the loop, you can't modify it inside the loop.

You can defeat this behavior by using an object rather than a scalar for 'count':

```
{% set count = [1] %}
```

You can now manipulate count inside a forloop or even an %include%. Here's how I increment count (yes, it's kludgy but oh well):

```
{% if count.append(count.pop() + 1) %}{% endif %} {# increment count by 1 #}
```

---

#### Or...

```
{% set count = [] %}
{% for something-that-loops %}
   {% set __ = count.append(1) %} 
   <div> Lorem ipsum meepzip dolor...
   {{ count|length }}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

*(From comments by @eyettea and @PYB)*

Comment: Peter Hollingsworth. Thanks a lot for that info, helped me a lot.

Comment: Another solution that's a bit cleaner imo is to initialize an empty list `{% set count = [] %}`, add an item to the list in every loop `{% set __ = index.append(1) %}` and use the length to display the index `index|length`.

Comment: Also, you can use [do](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#expression-statement) statement like this `{% do index.append(1) %}`
 But you have to add extention described [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/extensions/#expression-statement)

Comment: Correcting @eyettea 's clean solution:                                                      
Another solution that's a bit cleaner imo is to initialize an empty list `{% set count = [ ] %}`, add an item to the list in every loop `{% set __ = count.append(1) %}` and use the length to display the count `count|length`

Answer (score 20):

*Here's my solution:*

**Put all the counters in a dictionary:**

```
{% set counter = {
    'counter1': 0,
    'counter2': 0,
    'etc': 0,
    } %}
```

**Define a macro to increment them easily:**

```
{% macro increment(dct, key, inc=1)%}
    {% if dct.update({key: dct[key] + inc}) %} {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

**Now, whenever you want to increment the 'counter1' counter, just do:**

```
{{ increment(counter, 'counter1') }}
```

Comment: Elegant solution to a messy problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Very good! I needed a cumulative counting index rolling across two nested for loops. This works great for that use case.

Comment: agreed, this is very elegant!

Answer (score 6):

if anyone want to add a value inside loop then you can use this its working 100%

```
{% set ftotal= {'total': 0} %} 
{%- for pe in payment_entry -%}
    {% if ftotal.update({'total': ftotal.total + 5}) %}{% endif %} 
{%- endfor -%}

{{ftotal.total}}
```

output  = 5

Comment: excellent solution but you should have explained little bit for beginners

Answer (score 2):

Came searching for Django's way of doing this and found this post. Maybe someone else need the django solution who come here.

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    {{ forloop.counter }} {# starting index 1 #}
    {{ forloop.counter0 }} {# starting index 0 #}

    {# do your stuff #}
{% endfor %}
```

Read more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: That's Django Template Engine, OP asked for jinja2

Comment: Thanks that helped for me!

Answer (score 2):

I was struggle with this behavior too. I wanted to change div class in jinja based on counter. I was surprised that pythonic way did not work. Following code was reseting my counter on each iteration, so I had only red class.

```
{% if sloupec3: %}
    {% set counter = 1 %}
    {% for row in sloupec3: %}
        {% if counter == 3 %}
            {% set counter = 1 %}        
        {% endif %} 

        {% if  counter == 1: %}
           <div class="red"> some red div </div>
        {% endif %} 

        {% if counter == 2: %}
           <div class="gray"> some gray div </div>
        {% endif %} 

        {% set counter = counter + 1 %} 

    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

I used loop.index like this and it works:

```
{% if sloupec3: %}

    {% for row in sloupec3: %} 

        {% if  loop.index % 2 == 1: %}
           <div class="red"> some red div </div>
        {% endif %} 

        {% if loop.index % 2 == 0: %}
           <div class="gray"> some gray div </div>
        {% endif %}  

    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to shed more light into this problem.
Jinja2 variables behaves differently from that of conventional scripting languages, you can't modify the variable in a for loop.Hence to bypass this behaviour you can use a dictionary, since you can change the value of the dictionary.

```
**{% set margin={"margin_value":0} %}** 
{% for lang in language %}
<ul>
    <li style="margin-right: {{ margin.margin_value}}px">{{ lang }}</li>
</ul>
**{% if margin.update({"margin_value":margin.margin_value + 2}) %} 
{% endif %}** 
{% endfor %}
```

In the above code the value of the dictionary is being modified.