# Jinja2 variable out of scope

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I've the following template:

```
{% set rotator = 1 %}
{% for idx in range(1, count|int + 1) %}
{% if rotator == 4 %}
  {% set rotator = 1 %}
{% endif %}
{
  "id": "{{ '%02d' % idx }}",
  "value": "{{rotator}}"
},
{% set rotator = rotator + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

this template doesn't work because of the issue discussed here [How to increment a variable on a for loop in jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537439/how-to-increment-a-variable-on-a-for-loop-in-jinja-template)
For `doesn't work` I mean that the rotator is always one and doesn't change.

How then could I overcome to the following issue?

Comment: https://fabianlee.org/2016/10/18/saltstack-setting-a-jinja2-variable-from-an-inner-block-scope/

Comment: So what is the problem you are trying to solve? For example a single change to `"value": "{{rotator - 1 + idx}}"` gives results that one person might deem reasonable. But how is anyone supposed to know what your expectations are?

Comment: My expectations are that rotator must have the following pattern 1,2,3,1,2,3, etc...

Comment: That's not your expectation, that's an approximation of a solution to a problem introduced by your attempted solution - there's no need for any "`rotator`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template:

```
{% for idx in range(1, count|int + 1) %}
{
  "id": "{{ '%02d' % idx }}",
  "value": "{{ (idx+2)%3+1 }}"
},
{% endfor %}
```

The result (for `count=7`):

```
{
  "id": "01",
  "value": "1"
},
{
  "id": "02",
  "value": "2"
},
{
  "id": "03",
  "value": "3"
},
{
  "id": "04",
  "value": "1"
},
{
  "id": "05",
  "value": "2"
},
{
  "id": "06",
  "value": "3"
},
{
  "id": "07",
  "value": "1"
},
```

I leave the ending `,` because you did not specify what to do with it either.