# Error when using set tag in jinja template ('set'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?)

Tags: django, jinja2

Basically i want to count variable inside a loop in HTML page. For that i want to use set tag as explained in this example:

[How to increment a variable on a for loop in jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537439/how-to-increment-a-variable-on-a-for-loop-in-jinja-template)

When i use the set tag in my html page i get this error:
Django Version: 2.0.5

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
Invalid block tag on line 98: 'set'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

I can't really find another way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Jinja2 and not Django template language?

Comment: Thank you Alasdair for your reply im using this.

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
         'DIRS': ['./templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
    
]

Comment: You have only have one template engine with  `BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates'` , so you aren’t using Jinja2.

Comment: Thank you, so if i use jinja template does it have built-in set tag or do i have to make a custom tag?

Comment: It has a set tag, as shown in [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537439/how-to-increment-a-variable-on-a-for-loop-in-jinja-template). Note that Django discourages too much logic in the templates, there may be a way to solve your problem without setting variables in the template, which means you wouldn't have the complication of switching to Jinja2 templates.

Comment: right! Thank you