# How can I iterate a list, index by index, using jinja

Tags: python, html, web, flask, jinja2

That's my code:

```
{%block content%}
    {% for i in posts %}
        {% set x = x + 1 -%}
        <p style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px 5px; border-radius: 5px;">{{ i[x] }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('redirectposts') }}">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Posts</button>
    </form>
{%endblock%}
```

Btw, I set x as 0 in the render_template, as you can see here:

```
return render_template('index.html', titulo="Home", posts=lista, x = 0)
```

The 'posts' variable receives a large list with some strings. I want to know how can I iterate those strings, starting at the index[0] to the last one, putting them in the "p" tag, as a loop that repeat that structure.

I tried the code above, but it only returned the first index, not the rest, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment a variable on a for loop in jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537439/how-to-increment-a-variable-on-a-for-loop-in-jinja-template)

Comment: still not working :/

Answer (score 1):

Further, if you want both an index and a value, you can do something like

```
{% for i, v in e %}
<div>{{ i }}: {{ v }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and pass in an enumeration.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    stuff = ['first', 'second', 'third']
    return render_template('index.html', e = enumerate(stuff))
```

which will give you

```
0: first
1: second
2: third
```

Comment: I did it right now, but it didn't work, same result :(

Comment: You can also just use `{{loop.index}}` instead of enumerate.

Comment: Indeed. But passing generators in to templates can solve a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the index. Try:

```
 {% for i in posts %}
        <p style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px 5px; border-radius: 5px;">{{ i }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

It automatically loops over the items with the for loop. This would also mean you don't need to pass x into the template.