# incrementing variable in custom tags

Tags: python, html

I am trying to display all of the items inside of an array in a for loop but the problem is that I do not know how I can increment a variable that will be taken as index inside of the array, Here is my code:

```
{% set counter = 0 %}
{% for entry in msr.history %}
<tr>
  <td>
    {{entry.date_str}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{entry.pos}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{entry.user}}
  </td>
  <td> {{commentaire[counter]}}
  </td>
  {{counter.increment}}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

the problem in the code is that "counter" will always be equal to 0 so when I print my array it prints the 0th index all the time. I tried calling a python function by writing {{counter.increment}} but the function is not getting called. If you want to see the function here it is:

```
class Counter:
    count = 0

    def increment(self):
        print("test") <--- (doesn't even get printed)
        self.count += 1
        return ""
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components) will help you.

Comment: I have read the information on the site you have sent me but I don't understand how I could use the same method in order to increment my variable as what you sent me was in React, could you please explain it to me? Thank you for your time and your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first line counter is variable. It have not increment method, so print("test") never printed.

Comment: Yes exactly but do you know if there is a way to get around this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537439/how-to-increment-a-variable-on-a-for-loop-in-jinja-template

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been stuck since yesterday and I can finaly advance now